# Bot Framework + NodeJS: Ending Dialog/Conversation and Promise Chaining

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, botframework

I'm a bit on the new side to Bot Framework and I've dealing with some learning curve issues. One of such issues if ending conversations the correct way when there's some complex logic going on around it. Case in point, I have something similar to this in two different spots in my code:

```
someFunction(var)
  .then(success => {
    return someOtherFunction(someOtherVar)
  })
  .then(success => {
    if (success) {
      return yetAnotherFunction(otherVar)
    } else {
      session.endConversation('I'm done with this conversation.') //Change this with session.endDialog but get same result
    }
  })
  .then(success => {
    builder.Prompts.confirm('Are you sure?')
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
  })
```

Now, the issue here is that if I end the conversation/dialog the chained promises seem to go on despite me not returning a new promise. I can see in the logs that the conversation/dialog has ended correctly and yet I get an error afterwards that reads as follows:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prompt' of undefined
    at Object.confirm
```

or an error related whatever I have in the code instead of `builder.Prompts.confirm()`.

To that end, I'm starting to believe that my pattern for chaining `Promises` is perhaps not quite right. My question is then multifaceted:

Is there a consistent way to break the chain of promises at a given point?

or

Is there a better way to walk through several promises that allows a more clean break?

Comment: What are you specifically trying to do by calling `endConversation()`. Generally this method is a bit confusing, so it might not actually be doing what you think its going to do. Additionally, can you specify where the promises pick back up in your code when you mention "chained promises seem to go on despite me not returning a new promise"

Comment: @MarkB Maybe my issue is with not completely understanding the nuances of `endConversation()`. I assumed, probably wrongly, that by calling such a function the code would stop going forward because, well, it's the end of the conversation. On the other hand, the code seems to be picking up in the following `.then()`, immediately after calling the `endConversation()`. The error I mentioned refers always to that line in that file.

Comment: Yes, in this case `endConversation()` doesn't include any functionality that would abort a promise chain early, which appears to be what you are trying to do. It is meant to do a few operations connector-side that clean up the conversation.

Comment: @MarkB Thnak you, sir. Seems as though it’s a matter of me just finding a suitable solution for braking the chain of promises. From my reading, I was not aware that not returning a new promise but calling a new ‘then’ meant an implied resolved promise is returned. Tricky tricky 